# PHP - Show data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following PHP code for a filtered listing of data.
Date Filter - does not show the date "inclusive"
Name filter (opp) = not responding

php:

```
Db::queryAll("SELECT * FROM kontrola WHERE datum_pridania >= '$datumz' AND datum_pridania <= '$datumk' || autor_id = '$opp' ORDER BY datum_pridania DESC");
```

html:

```
<tr>
    <td>Od:<input name="datumz" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="datepicker" placeholder="začiatočný dátum" style="border-radius: 3px;background-color: rgb(229, 226, 230);border: 3px solid #e5e2e6;margin-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>Do:<input name="datumk" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="date" placeholder="koncový dátum" style="border-radius: 3px;background-color: rgb(229, 226, 230);border: 3px solid #e5e2e6;margin-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>Meno OP:<input name="opp" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="meno operátora" style="border-radius: 3px;background-color: rgb(229, 226, 230);border: 3px solid #e5e2e6;margin-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Filtrovať" style="background-color: #dde53d;border: none;color: black;height: 35px;width: 85px;margin-left: 10px;"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But it seems like you didn't print anything in the HTML using PHP.

Comment: Try to replace `||` with `OR` in the sql query

Comment: FYI : `datum_pridania >= '$datumz' AND datum_pridania <= '$datumk' OR autor_id = '$opp'` is equivalent to `( datum_pridania >= '$datumz' AND datum_pridania <= '$datumk') OR autor_id = '$opp'`, is this what you want ?

Comment: I entered instead of || "OR" but without result

Comment: 2nd problem = resolved
1st Problem = Why is not the date inclusive displayed?
Example:
If I enter the date from 4.1.2019 to 4.1.2019 = no result is displayed

Comment: I see no PHP code and I only see a db query, nothing setting any variables to print in your html.  Please show all your code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Whatever `DB` is I think it's a huge liability from a security perspective.